# File Search in Rust Multithreading Deadlock

Tags: multithreading, rust, filesystems

I want to use Rust to recursively search the file system for similar files. The main program (`fn search_compare`) checks whether further directories have been added to a vector by the threads for checking. If the maximum number of threads has not yet been reached, a new thread is started for the next directory added.

In the threads, the directories contained in the directory are added to the vector. The files are then checked for similarity.

```rs
const MAX_AMOUNT_THREADS:i32 = 100;
pub fn search_compare(s_string: &'static str, start_directory:&'static str, amount_res:usize){
    let init_search_result : SearchResult = SearchResult{
        path:"".to_string(),
        lev_dist: 100000,
        jac_dist: 1.0,
        score: 10000.0
    };

    //saves the files with the biggest score
    let mut search_result :Arc<Mutex<Vec<SearchResult>>>= Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![init_search_result;amount_res]));
    let mut amount_threads: Arc<Mutex<i32>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

    if check_directory(start_directory){
        //saves the directories that have to be checked
        let mut directories_to_check : Arc<Mutex<Vec<String>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![start_directory.to_string()]));
        let mut directories_to_check_are_existing : bool = true;
        let mut amount_threads_running_not_zero : bool = true;
        while(directories_to_check_are_existing || amount_threads_running_not_zero) {
            let mut current_amount_threads= amount_threads.lock().unwrap();
            if(*current_amount_threads < MAX_AMOUNT_THREADS) {
                *current_amount_threads+=1;
                drop(current_amount_threads);

                let cloned_search_result = Arc::clone(&search_result);
                let cloned_directories_to_check = Arc::clone(&directories_to_check);
                let cloned_amount_threads = Arc::clone(&amount_threads);

                //gets the next directory to check
                let mut directories = directories_to_check.lock().unwrap();
                let mut directory_to_check="".to_string();
                if(directories.len() > 0) {
                    directory_to_check = directories.pop().unwrap();
                }
                drop(directories);

                //starts thread for this
                if(directory_to_check != "") {
                    thread::spawn(move || {
                        search_compare_rek(s_string.to_string(), directory_to_check, cloned_search_result, cloned_directories_to_check, cloned_amount_threads);
                    });
                }
            } else {
                drop(current_amount_threads);
            }


            //check if directories need to be checked
            let mut directories = directories_to_check.lock().unwrap();
            if directories.len() == 0{
                directories_to_check_are_existing = false;
            } else {
                directories_to_check_are_existing = true;
            }
            println!("Directories to check {}",directories.len().to_string());
            drop(directories);

            //check if threads are running
            let current_amount_threads= amount_threads.lock().unwrap();
            if *current_amount_threads == 0 {
                amount_threads_running_not_zero = false;
            } else{
                amount_threads_running_not_zero = true;
            }
            println!("Current Threads running {}", current_amount_threads);
            drop(current_amount_threads);

        }

        //print the result
        let finished_vector = search_result.lock().unwrap();
        print_search_result(& *finished_vector);
        println!("Finished");
    } else{
        println!("no dic")
    }

}

fn search_compare_rek(s_string: String,search_path:String,search_results:Arc<Mutex<Vec<SearchResult>>>, directories_to_check: Arc<Mutex<Vec<String>>>, curr_amount_threads: Arc<Mutex<i32>>){
    match get_directory_content(&search_path) {
        Ok(directory_content) => {
            println!("{}",search_path);

            //add the directories to the vector for checking
            let mut directories = directories_to_check.lock().unwrap();
            for s in &directory_content.directories{
                let path = directory_content.path.clone();
                directories.push(path +"/"+ s.as_str());
            }
            drop(directories);

            //compare the files
            for files in &directory_content.files{
                let filename = String::from(search_path.clone() + "/" + files);
                let compare_result=compare(&s_string, &filename);
                let current_result = SearchResult{
                    path: filename.clone(),
                    lev_dist: compare_result.0,
                    jac_dist: 1.0-compare_result.1,
                    score: compare_result.0 as f64 * (1.0-compare_result.1)
                };
                let mut results = search_results.lock().unwrap();
                check_insert(current_result, &mut *results);
            }
        }
        Err(_err)=>{
            eprintln!("Could not get directory content {}", search_path);
        }
    }

    //end the threads, decrement the counter
    let mut curr_amount_threads = curr_amount_threads.lock().unwrap();
    *curr_amount_threads -=1;
    println!("Thread beendet {}, {}", search_path, curr_amount_threads);
}
```

At the beginning everything runs normally, threads are started, terminated and new threads are started again. After a while, `current_amount_threads` is at `MAX_AMOUNT_THREADS` and `directories_to_check` is at 0. Then none of the threads are terminated. The loop in the main program runs the whole time.

I think the threads are somehow in a deadlock. But in the main program, `directories_to_check` and `amount_threads` are always released again after use. So the threads should also be able to access these two mutexes and there should be no deadlock.

I have tried to find the error with console output. Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: This seems like one of those cases, where using [channels](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) is the better solution